# How to add Category, Websites, and Low Stock Date columns to Low Stock Report in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I want to add 3 new columns to the Low Stock Report in Magento. I need to display the product's categories, websites, and low stock date. I've tried adding this line ->joinInventoryItem('low_stock_date') to add the low stock date but I am not getting any value.

For the websites, I've tried adding this line:

```
->joinField('websites',
'catalog/product_website',
'website_id',
'product_id=entity_id',
null,
'left'
)
```

But I am also not getting any values.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there at first you need to prepare a collection by joining tables.
For that see the example of joining the tables in the answer provided in the below link.

[joining the tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27731719/magento-custom-table-join-with-catalog-product/27732198#27732198)

Another possible way would be using renderer to render the value in the grid.For that please refer to the answer that i provided in the link below.

[using renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26920895/how-to-properly-add-a-shipping-description-column-in-magento-order-grid/26924377#26924377)

Or you can check the tutorial provided by Inchoo [here](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-renderer-for-a-custom-column-in-magento-grid/)

Hope this will help.